# How to use Swift 4 Decodable when JSON root in mutliple array's with different properties

Tags: ios, json, swift

So I've been using Swift 4's new Decodable protocol and it's been great, but now I've come across an instance that I can't find an answer. I'm trying to use decodable to parse the Reddit Comments API response. Here is a quick example. (Note this isn't the full response, just something quick for example)

Here is a quick example of my problem. If you look at the "data" key inside of "children" the dictionaries contain different data. Is there a way to have two different JSON objects in the `children` array depending on what contents they have or based on their position in the array?

```
[{
    "kind": "Listing",
    "data": {
        "modhash": "kskppiefdzafc020177a3995ccd7f13b4ba0a8ca70e691a510",
        "whitelist_status": "all_ads",
        "children": [{
            "kind": "t3",
            "data": {
                "domain": "i.redd.it",
                "approved_at_utc": null,
                "mod_reason_by": null,
                "selftext_html": "Hello world!!!"
            }
        }]
    }
}, {
    "kind": "Listing",
    "data": {
        "modhash": "kskppiefdzafc020177a3995ccd7f13b4ba0a8ca70e691a510",
        "whitelist_status": "all_ads",
        "children": [{
            "kind": "t3",
            "data": {
                "domain": "i.redd.it",
                "approved_at_utc": null,
                "author": null,
                "body": "Hello world"
            }
        }]
    }

}]
```

Essentially what I'm curious is possible is this....

```
public struct CommentRoot: Decodable {
    struct Datafield: Decodable {
        let modhash: String
        let whitelist_status: String
        let children: [Comment]? // <------ Can be 1 of 2 types of comment that vary.
        let after: String?
        let before: String?
    }
    let data: Datafield
    let kind: String
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hop it will help you

```
import Foundation

struct Children : Decodable {

    let data : DataInfo?
    let kind : String?


    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data
        case kind = "kind"
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        data = try DataInfo(from: decoder)
        kind = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .kind)
    }


}

       struct DataInfo : Decodable {

        let approvedAtUtc : String?
        let author : String?
        let body : String?
        let domain : String?
        let children : [Children]?
        let modhash : String?
        let whitelistStatus : String?


        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case approvedAtUtc = "approved_at_utc"
            case author = "author"
            case body = "body"
            case domain = "domain"
            case children = "children"
            case modhash = "modhash"
            case whitelistStatus = "whitelist_status"
        }
        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            approvedAtUtc = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .approvedAtUtc)
            author = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .author)
            body = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .body)
            domain = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .domain)
            children = try values.decodeIfPresent([Children].self, forKey: .children)
            modhash = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .modhash)
            whitelistStatus = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .whitelistStatus)
        }


    }
```

Comment: So, is your suggestion to have a decodable object that handles all values for both objects that can exist in `children`?

Comment: yes. it will handle both objects  thats why  values.decodeIfPresent i am using .

Comment: You shouldn't name your struct `Data`. Btw code only answers are not helpful. You should explain your solution instead of simply dumping some code and asking the OP to try it.

Comment: @LeoDabus thank for suggestion . i will modify as per request soon